# Best way to add delay before checking window.onerror

Tags: javascript

I have a classic asp application which has a following code right when the app opens:

Window.onerror = handleErr

I need add delay in checking error as the error displayed by handleErr function seems to be occurring prematurely. I think it’s caused by network delay. After refreshing app in client browser, the error message goes away. How can add delay before calling ‘window.onerror’?! I want to keep checking for say 5 seconds and call handleErr only if error still persists

I researched settimeout() function and thought I could the line following as:

Window.onerror = settimeout(handleErr,5000)

But it will just delay call but will not recheck that error is still before calling

Comment: `Window.onerror = settimeout(handleErr,5000)` just causes `handleErr` to be called 5s after page load regardless of wether or not there was an error. `setTimeout` returns a token for the timeout. `Window.onerror` wants a function reference. So you actually need something like `Window.onerror = () => { setTimeout(handleErr, 5000); }`. If you actually want to delay the setting of `onerror`, you'd use something like `setTimeout(() => {Window.onerror = handleError}, 5000);`.

Comment: What do you mean by "*only if error still persists*"? An exception occurs only once.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @Ouroborus and @Bergi for your responses.

The fact that if I refresh the page in client browser, the page works fine without `onerror` exception in other words, the `onerror` exception occurs prematurely. I simply want to add 5 seconds delay and check for `onerror` exception again and assign `handleErr` function only if `onerror` exception is still true.

Per recommendation of @Ouroborus, I replaced `Window.onerror = handleErr` with your recommended `setTimeout(() => {Window.onerror = handleError}, 5000)`. It too essentially delayed setting of `onerror` not sure how to really wait for five seconds and then check again if the `window.onerror` exception is still true. If it is then only call `handleErr` function but if not, continue loading the rest of the page. I hope I am making it clear as to what I want to happen. Thanks again and looking forward to further recommendations.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. OnErrror is not a property to check for error, it's an event handler. When you assign `Window.onerror = handleErr`, the handleErr gets called each time an error event is raised by the window. If you do `setTimeout(() => {Window.onerror = handleError}, 5000)`, it delays setting the event handler and your error events are ignored for the first 5 seconds. If your `handleErr` method is still getting executed, it means that error is occurring even after 5 sec. 
I think ur approach isn't right. You should look into why the error is occurring instead of ignoring it.